# Prove that$ f(x)$ is integrable on$ [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that the function defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \
       \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n}  & \text{if} &\frac{1}{2^n} < x \leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\\
        0 &\text{if} &x=0\\
       \end{cases}$$

Is this Riemann integrable?

Comment: i can't english well cuz i'm korean... sorry... help me!

Comment: $f(x)$ doesn't contain any $x$ variables..

Comment: @장원봉 i edited your question..is this want you wanted to write?

Comment: thank you @MariosGretsas very very thank you but need some two changes.. first the function value is (-1)^(n-1) / 2^n not (-1)^n -1  / 2^n and the second is Inequality lake which the range x<_ 1/2^(n-1) not x<1/2^(n-1)

Comment: @Wyllich sorrry i'm korean.. the precise range is that i commented to Marios Gretsas(6 mins ago) and x is on [0,1]

Comment: @장원봉 what do you mean by x<_1/2^(n-1)??

Comment: @MariosGretsas thank you!! for edited the Inequality lake is ≤ 1/2^(n-1) not < 1/2^(n-1) Except for this, it's perfect. and Thank you very much for helping me. I'm typing through a translator, but it's incredibly nice to be here.

Comment: @장원봉 is it ok now?

Comment: @MariosGretsas wow! thank you !! perfect!

Comment: Now for $f(x)$ is what you want to write or $f_n(x)$ which is a sequence of functions?

Comment: @MariosGretsas f(x) is what i want to write not a sequence of functions If you don't touch it right now, Perfect. one more time thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll try to decompose the integral into a sum as $f(x)$ takes different values depending on $x$' value. Because we're not sure about the convergence of the integral, we'll work with finite sums to begin with:

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^N \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n}\mathrm{d}x$$

$$ = \sum_{n=1}^N[\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2^n}][\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n}]$$

$$ =\sum_{n=1}^N [\frac{1}{2^{n}}][\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n}]$$

$$ =- \sum_{n=1}^N (\frac{-1}{4})^n$$

Because this sum converges when $N \to +\infty$ , we can prove the convergence of the integral:

$$ \frac{1}{2^{1-1}}=1 \text{ and } \frac{1}{2^n} \underset{n \to +\infty} \to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

We shall see that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

$f$ is measurable since:

$$f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f \cdot\chi_{\left\langle\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]}$$

The sequence $\left(\sum_{n=1}^N f \cdot\chi_{\left\langle\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]} \right)_{N=1}^\infty$ is dominated by an integrable function on $[0,1]$:
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^Nf \cdot\chi_{\left\langle\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]}\right| \leq  \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n} < 1$$

Thus, we can use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to swap the sum and the integral:
\begin{align}\int_\limits{[0,1]} f\,d\lambda &= \int_\limits{[0,1]}\sum_{n=1}^\infty f \cdot\chi_{\left\langle\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]}\,d\lambda\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_\limits{[0,1]} f \cdot\chi_{\left\langle\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right]}\,d\lambda\\ 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n}\,d\lambda \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n}}\\ 
&= \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n} \\
&= \frac{1}{5}
\end{align}

Now, the set of discontinuities of $f$ is $\left\{\frac{1}{2^n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Since it is a countable set, its Lebesgue measure is zero so by the [Lebesgue's integrability condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability), we get that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$. Since $f$ is also Lebesgue integrable on $[0, 1]$, the values of Riemann and Lebesgue integrals must conincide.

Hence:

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{5}$$

Comment: Yup. Good call on the missing $(-1)^n$. I was worried about my proof.

Comment: Lebesque integrable does not imply Riemann integrability

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, my bad. All we got is that the Riemann integral, if it exists, must be $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: @ mechanodroid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability, seems this function is indead Riemann integrable

Comment: @dEmigOd Thanks, I have added the argument in my answer.